# Readability of thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm used to writing templates like this:

```
<div class="person">
    ${name}
</div>
```

This seems much more readable for me, in that I can see the variables outside of the tags themselves. Currently in thymeleaf, I would need to do:

```
<div class="person" th:text="${name}" />
```

Or:

```
<div class="person" th:text="${name}">
    ${name} // this text will be replaced and doesn't matter
</div>
```

Is there a way to enter in the variable like I have at the top?

Comment: The point of Thymeleaf is that templates are **valid and renderable HTML**, this allows for easier 1) styling, 2) validation, 3) formatting. Personally _I think_ that Thymelead is far more readable than mixing multiple different languages. Now - the catch - the "I think" means that this is opinion based, so again off topic.

Comment: P.S. [worth reading](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html)

Comment: If you want it that way go with JSP and the Standard Tag Library.At the moment you are ordering beef that should taste like fish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use [expression inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-inlining) for this.

```
<div class="person">
    [[${name}]]
</div>
```

In the documentation I linked, it does have a discussion of using expression inlining vs natural templating.  I personally prefer natural templating in most cases.

Comment: Eugh - that's heinous. Seems like the very definition of "worst of both worlds". This is meant for very rare situations where the standard syntax doesn't suffice - it's absolutely **not** meant to be an alternative syntax.

Comment: If you are using the latest thymeleaf -- 3.0 at the time of this, it does it automatically.  If you are using 2.0, you probably have to put `th:inline="text"` in your tag.... which is even uglier.

Comment: @David542 if this makes you happy _please_ just use Freemarker. Don't abuse Thymeleaf this way - it'll make people cry.

Comment: @BoristheSpider what would be the conventional way to do the above then? Would you do it as `<div th:text="${name}" />` or `<div th:text="${name}" ></div>` or `<div th:text="${name}" >name</div>`or something else?

Comment: @David542 you would put some text in the `div`, that's the **whole point**! You create a page that looks like it should when viewed without rendering. `<div th:text="${name}" >John Smith</div>` for example.

Comment: @David542 -- if you want to go completely the thymeleaf way, it should look like this: `<div th:text="${name}">David542</div>`.  That way when you open it in the browser (without a server), it looks like it's working (e.g. it looks like `${name}` is replaced with David542).  And when you run it through a server where the thymeleaf is interpreted, David542 is actually replaced with `${name}`.  However, in practice I always write `<div th:text="${name}" />` just because it's more succinct.